# Load plugins RequireJS on click

Tags: jquery, requirejs

New to RequireJS. Is there any way I could organize this better:

```
require(["jquery"], function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('#id').live('click',function(){
            require(["mainplugin","otherplugin","thirdplugin"], function(){
                $('#id').pluginName();
            });

        });
    });
});
```

The rest of the plugins should only be loaded when the el is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the first `$(function() ...` wrapper, as the code will be executed as soon as jquery is loaded.

```
require(["jquery"], function($) {
        $('#id').live('click',function(){
            require(["mainplugin","otherplugin","thirdplugin"], function(){
                $('#id').pluginName();
            });
        });
});
```